# assign a shelved changlist in perforce?

Tags: perforce, shelve

I'm really excited about Perforce's new shelve command. They say that you should be able to "reassign" the changelist to someone else, who can then unshelve it.

How do I reassign a shelved changelist? Is there a way to do it in p4v, or only at the commandline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the top of my head, because I don't have p4v at hand:
Select the pending changelist in your client, open the context-menu with a right mouseclick and select "shelve". On another client, you can browse to the pending changelists, select the right one and unshelve it; this results in a local pending changelist on this client.

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize that perforce was automatically filtering pending changelists by what I've checked out on my workspace.

Comment: This is the only way I know of to do this.  Note that doing things this way doesn't remove the changelist from the original owner's workspace, only creating a new one on your own workspace with the same changes.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in CLI? Did not see it in the [p4 shelve docs](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_shelve.html)

Answer (score 3):

The new version of Perforce (2010.1) allows you to right click a changelist that has shelved files and select "Change Ownership...".